# Calculating from multiple tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to take a list of lists of tuple and turn each list of tuples into a single tuple. Like this:

Currently have:

```
[[("Erikson,Ann",2.0,3),("Erikson,Ann",3.33,3)],[("Lewis,Buck",2.66,1), 
  ("Lewis,Buck",2.0,3)],[("Smith,John",0.0,1),("Smith,John",1.66,3), 
  ("Smith,John",1.33,3)],[("Torvell,Sarah",4.0,3)]]
```

And I want the form to be a single list of tuples. One tuple for each persons name. 
Along with combining the list of tuples into a single tuple I want to use the second and third elements of each tuple to calculate the gpa of the person. The second number is the grade point for that class and the third number is the credits for the class.
What I need to do is take the sum of credits * gradepoint for each tuple and then divide that sum by the sum of all the credits in each tuple.

What i have so far, that doesn't work is this...

```
     calcGPA :: MyType2 -> MyType2 -> (String, Double, Double)
     calcGPA (a,b,c) (d,e,f) = (a, ((b*(fromIntegral c))+(e*(fromIntegral 
     f))/(b+e)), 
     (b+e))
```

Where i am passing in the first list of lists I show at the top of this post.

Am I going in the right direction to solve this problem. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Thank you

---

EDIT

Thank you for the help! Helped me understand what was actually going on. I wrote the cumulativeSums fuction as follow:

```
     cumulativeSums :: (Double, Int) -> (String, Double, Int) -> (Double, 
     Int)
     cumulativeSums (a,b) (c,d,e) = (a+(d*e), b+e)
```

I'm confused on the chunk of code you have above with the let. Where does this go? Do I put it in its own function that I call passing in the list of list of tuples?

Thank you

________________________________________________________________________________Now that im trying to output credits also

```
    calcGPA :: [(String, Double, Int)] -> (String, Double, Int)
    calcGPA grades = let name                        = (\ (name, _, _) -> 
    name) (head grades)
                         (name, weightedSum, sumOfWeights) = foldl 
    cumulativeSums (name, 0, 0) grades
                 gpa                         = weightedSum / sumOfWeights
                     in  (name, gpa, credits)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going in the right direction if you were planning on using `foldl` or `foldr` with your `calcGPA` function.

What we do when folding is we have a function with the result-so-far, the next element in a list, and the result-just-after. With `foldl`, which is most appropriate for sums, the type and arguments, as far as lists are concerned is:

```hs
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f startingResult items = …
```

We see that your function will need to be type `(b -> a -> b)`. Looking elsewhere in the type signature, the ultimate result of `foldl` is type `b`. The type of elements in the list is type `a`.

So what the function you provide `foldl` does is takes two arguments: the result-so-far and the next item in the list. It then expects your function to give back the result-just-after.

You "fold" in a new item to the result each time your function is run on the next element in the list. So let's look at what our list element type is and what our result type will be.

Our list element type is something like `(String, Double, Int)`. Our result type is `(Double, Int)`. So the type signature for our folding function is:

```hs
cumulativeSums :: (Double, Int) -> (String, Double, Int) -> (Double, Int)
```

So far so good. Now what about the other arguments to `foldl`? We know the `items` argument: it's our sublist for one person's grades. We know `f`, it's our `cumulativeSums` function we're going to write. What is `startingResult`? Well, both sums should start with 0, so it's `(0, 0)`. We have:

```hs
let name                        = (\ (name, _, _) -> name) (head grades)
    (weightedSum, sumOfWeights) = foldl cumulativeSums (0, 0) grades
    gpa                         = weightedSum / sumOfWeights
in  (name, gpa)
```

Now we write `cumulativeSums`. Remember, we're getting told the result-so-far and the item from the list. We just need to give back the result-just-after. See if you can write that part.

For the code already provided, I'd recommend writing your own version of it. There are some type errors related to mixing `Int`s and `Double`s in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Helped me understand what was actually going on. I updated my original post with where I am at with what you told me. I have a question that I state above.


Thank you

Comment: @Riley For the code with the `let`, that goes in another function, like `calcGPA grades = let …` So, that'll take in the grades for one person (a list of tuples) and produce one tuple with the name and GPA, using your new `cumulativeSums` function.

Comment: Does the cumulativeSums function above look correct?

Comment: Yes, except you'll have some minor type errors that shouldn't be too hard to correct, since it's similar to your original question.

Comment: I'm having issues putting the let block into a function. The equal sign after the (weightedSum, sumOfWeights)  line is giving me a error that it should be in a let. When I put it in a let I also get an error.

Comment: Make sure it's indented past the `let` on the line above (like the example).

Comment: I actually want my output of calcGPA(what i pass my list of tuples into) to return the credits also. I updated my calculcateGPA function, but i am having a hard time updating calcGPA. My code of where i am now is above. thanks

Comment: In that case, you can modify the code above to return `(name, gpa, sumOfWeights)`, since the "weights" are the credits. If you want, you can rename the variable.

Comment: I am getting an error on the first two lines of the let saying i have conflicting definitions of name. Any idea why this may be.

Comment: It looks like you define name twice: once in the `name =` line and once in the `(name, weightedSum, sumOfWeights) =` line. Once a variable like `name` is defined (in a certain scope), it can't be defined again. Either remove the first one or the second one.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go over each sub-list so you can accumulate values. Something like this:

```
averageGdp :: [[(String, Double, Double)]] -> [(String, Double, Double)]
averageGdp = fmap f
  where
    f             = (,,) <$> fst . head <*> totalAvg <*> totalCredit 
    fst (a, _, _) = a
    totalCredit   = getSum . foldMap (\(_, _, c) -> pure c)
    total         = getSum . foldMap (\(_, b, c) -> pure $ b * c)
    totalAvg      = (/) <$> total <*>  totalCredit
```

f takes the inner list as its input and produces a triple. You then map f over the outer list.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but I think the OP is a beginner and will not be able to understand much of the code above. Sometimes, it's better to stick to an elementary approach, which would be more helpful to the OP, even if less elegant.

Answer (score 2):

With this sort of grouping problems, I think it's a bit of a red herring that the data already looks grouped. Can you always be sure of that? What if the data looks like the following?

```
[[("Erikson,Ann",2.0,3),("Erikson,Ann",3.33,3),("Lewis,Buck",2.66,1)], 
 [("Lewis,Buck",2.0,3)]]
```

Or like this?

```
[[("Erikson,Ann",2.0,3),("Erikson,Ann",3.33,3),("Lewis,Buck",2.66,1)], []]
```

Notice that in the first example, one entry for `"Lewis,Buck"` is grouped together with entries for `"Erikson,Ann"`. The second example, on the other hand, contains an empty list.

Most attempts I've seen at solving problems like this does so by utilising **unsafe** (i.e. non-total) functions like `head`. This can lead to wrong implementations or run-time crashes.

Haskell is a great language exactly because you can use the type system to keep you honest. If the original input wasn't already grouped, it'd be safer to use ungrouped data. Otherwise, you can flatten the input using `concat`. I'm here assuming that the example data in the OP is called `sample`:

```
*Q52527030> concat sample
[("Erikson,Ann",2.0,3.0),("Erikson,Ann",3.33,3.0),("Lewis,Buck",2.66,1.0),
 ("Lewis,Buck",2.0,3.0),("Smith,John",0.0,1.0),("Smith,John",1.66,3.0),
 ("Smith,John",1.33,3.0),("Torvell,Sarah",4.0,3.0)]
```

This gives you a nice flat list on which you can perform a custom grouping operation:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

arrangeByFst :: Ord a => [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, [(b, c)])]
arrangeByFst = Map.toList . foldl updateMap Map.empty
  where updateMap m (x, y, z) = Map.insertWith (++) x [(y, z)] m
```

Here I've chosen to take a shortcut and use the built-in `Map` module, but otherwise, writing a function similar to `Map.insertWith` on a list of tuples isn't *too* hard.

This function takes a flat list of triples and groups them into pairs keyed by the first element, but with the other element being a list of data.

If you apply that to the flattened `sample` input, you get this:

```
*Q52527030> arrangeByFst $ concat sample
[("Erikson,Ann",[(3.33,3.0),(2.0,3.0)]),("Lewis,Buck",[(2.0,3.0),(2.66,1.0)]),
 ("Smith,John",[(1.33,3.0),(1.66,3.0),(0.0,1.0)]),("Torvell,Sarah",[(4.0,3.0)])]
```

This is a more robust approach because it doesn't rely on any particular assumptions about how data is ordered.

Each element in this list is a pair, where the first element is the name, and the second element is a list of grades. You can add a function to calculate the GPA of such a pair:

```
calculateGPA :: Fractional b => (a, [(b, b)]) -> (a, b)
calculateGPA (n, ts) = (n, sumOfGrades ts / numberOfGrades ts)
  where
    sumOfGrades grades = sum $ map (\(gp, c) -> gp * c) grades
    numberOfGrades grades = fromIntegral (length grades)
```

This function takes as input a tuple where the second element is a list of tuples `ts`. It calculates `sumOfGrades` by mapping each tuple of grade points `gp` and credits `c` into the product of the two, and then taking the `sum` of those numbers. It then divides that number by the length of the list of grades.

You can now map the list produced in the previous step to calculate the GPA of each person:

```
*Q52527030> map calculateGPA $ arrangeByFst $ concat sample
[("Erikson,Ann",7.995),("Lewis,Buck",4.33),("Smith,John",2.9899999999999998),
 ("Torvell,Sarah",12.0)]
```

Apart from using `Data.Map.Strict`, I've deliberately attempted to strike a balance between keeping things basic, but still safe. A more sophisticated approach could have used `fmap` instead of `map`, `join` instead of `concat`, more point-free style, and so on. There's always room for improvement.

Comment: I got the feeling it's safe to assume this is a part of a larger problem, presented to students gradually, in several installments, and so yes, it would be safe to assume it's already grouped as part of some previous assignment. as is usual, the OP was quite vague on this, of course. :)  good point about `head`, I've corrected my answer thanks to that.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner to do what you asked about:

```
import Control.Category ( (>>>) )

g :: [[(t, Double, Double)]] -> [(t, Double, Double)]
g = filter (not . null) >>>
      map (unzip3 >>> \ (a,b,c) -> (head a, sum (zipWith (*) b c) / sum c, sum c))
```

`unzip3 :: [(a, b, c)] -> ([a], [b], [c])` is in the Prelude.

`>>>` is the left-to-right function composition, `(f >>> g) x = g (f x)`.

`filter` makes sure all empty groups are removed before further processing.