# groupBy function which groups non-adjacent elements

Tags: haskell, grouping

The [groupBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) function groups the elements of a list when they are equal according to a user-defined predicate and when they are adjacent in the list. Is there a function for grouping elements without taking care of the adjacency?

I deal with polynomials of three variables. Here is an example of such a polynomial written as a sum of monomials:

```
p = (M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (1,0,0)}) :+: M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (0,1,0)})) :+: M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (1,0,0)})
```

That means that `p = 1.0 * x^1y^0z^0 + 1.0 * x^0y^1z^0 + 1.0 * x^1y^0z^0`. The first term and the third term are summable: they have the same `powers` and then we can add them and get `2.0 * x^1y^0z^0`. My goal is to do this addition, in order to simplify `p`.

I have a function which converts such a `p` to the list of the summed monomials:

```
>> toListOfMonomials p
[M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (1,0,0)}),M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (0,1,0)}),M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (1,0,0)})]
```

I want to group the monomials which have the same `powers`. If I do

```
groupBy ((==) `on` getPowers)
        (toListOfMonomials p)
```

then the two `M (Monomial {coefficient = 1.0, powers = (1,0,0)})` are not grouped because they are not adjacent.

A solution consists in sorting the list according to the powers before using `groupBy`. In this way, two (or more) monomials having the same `powers` are adjacent in the sorted list. To define an order on the powers (`powers` is a triplet of integers), I firstly define a Cantor pairing function:

```
cantorPairing :: (Int, Int) -> Int
cantorPairing (k1,k2) = (k1+k2)*(k1+k2+1) + 2*k2

cantorPairing' :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
cantorPairing' (k1,k2,k3) = cantorPairing(cantorPairing(k1,k2),k3)
```

then I can compare two `powers` by comparing their values under the Cantor pairing function:

```
groupBy ((==) `on` getPowers)
        (sortBy (compare `on` (cantorPairing' . getPowers)) (toListOfMonomials p))
```

This gives the desired result: with this result I can easily sum the two monomials having the same `powers`.

But that looks heavy, doesn't it? Isn't there a `groupBy` function which groups also non-adjacent elements? Otherwise, is there a more rapid way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I would move the sorting into `toListOfMonomials` itself. An addition function that can combine like terms immediately might be preferable to a separate `:+:` constructor.

Comment: @chepner I agree. Good point. Thanks!

Comment: I generally do this sort of thing by going through Data.Map.  It's about equally verbose, but sometimes it's useful that `(cantorPairing' . getPowers)` get called n times instead of O(n log n) times.

Comment: This type of question seems to come up regularly. Like @bergey I usually use `Data.Map` for the grouping step. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535999/126014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I cannot imagine general `groupBy` function that would work faster than O(n^2) time, but you may use something like this

```
groupBy2 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy2 = go [] where
  go acc comp [] = acc
  go acc comp (h:t) =
    let (hs, nohs) = partition (comp h) t
    in go ((h:hs):acc) comp nohs
```

It works exactly like regular `groupBy`, but it joins non-adjacent element classes.

However, if you are going to use `on` function the problem becomes a bit simplier, as we may use it's result as key for a map:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

groupOn :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupOn f =
  let unpack = fmap snd . M.toList
      fld m a = case M.lookup (f a) m of
        Nothing -> M.insert (f a) [a] m
        Just as -> M.insert (f a) (a:as) m
  in unpack . foldl fld M.empty
```

This is more efficient equivalent of

```
groupOn' f = groupBy2 ((==) `on` f)
```

(modulo ordering)

And btw – triplets and pairs already have defined Ord instance, you may compare them just like `Int`s

Comment: Thanks. I have generalized [my code](https://github.com/stla/multipol) to deal with polynomials having an arbitrary number of variables, and now the powers are lists, not triplets. But lists with the same length also have an Ord instance (I didn't know), therefore there's no need of using a Cantor pairing. Haskell is very fun to program such things.

Comment: Lists' Ord instance does not care about length. If elements match, the longer is greater.

Comment: If you care about preserving the order of the sublists you need to reverse the source list on the way in: ``unpack . foldl' fld M.empty . reverse``